# What's the meaning of "to make a point"?

Tags: meaning

Could you please tell me what the meaning of "to make a point" is in this case:

> It’s three in the morning, and we are making our way from southern to
>   northern Utah, when the weather changes from the dry chill of the desert
>   to the freezing gales of an alpine winter. Ice claims the road. Snowflakes
>   flick against the windshield like tiny insects, a few at first, then so many
>   the road disappears. We push forward into the heart of the storm. The van
>   skids and jerks. The wind is furious, the view out the window pure white.
>   Richard pulls over. He says we can’t go any further.
>   Dad takes the wheel, Richard moves to the passenger seat, and Mother
>   lies next to me and Audrey on the mattress. Dad pulls onto the highway
>   and accelerates, rapidly, **as if to make a point**, until he has doubled
>   Richard’s speed.

Extract from *Educated* by Tara Westover

Comment: 'Dad' is in effect 'saying' that the weather conditions should not prove all that difficult for a proficient driver; in fact, a decent driver could manage a much higher speed despite the conditions. // I'm with Richard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dad pulls onto the highway and accelerates, rapidly, as if to make a point, until he has doubled Richard’s speed.

"to make a point" usually refers to bringing forward a good argument (point) or an idea in a conversation.

Here, "Dad" accelerates rapidly as if he wanted to point out that this weather is not all that bad for a proficient driver.